# Node exec bash commands after finishing first command

Tags: node.js, bash, terminal

Using Node to automate some of my bash processes.

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");

let buildCommand = "docker build -t vm1:v1 ./nginx1 " 
let runCommand = "docker run -d -p 6001:6001 --name clientvm1 vm1:v1"


//run first command

 exec(buildCommand, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
        return;
    }
    if (stderr) {
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        return;
    }
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
});

//run second command

   exec(runCommand, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
        return;
    }
    if (stderr) {
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        return;
    }
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
});
```

What is the best way to have the second command wait until the first command is done?

Answer (score 1):

I am certainly no expert, but perhaps you could wrap the second method in an async method and await the first within?

```js
method1() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(exec(buildCommand));
  }).catch((err) => throw new Error(err));
}

async method2() {
  await method1();
  exec(runCommand);
}
```

This is likely far from fool-proof, but I think it should do what you're looking for.